# Winform dialog: detect begin and end of move

Tags: winforms, move, detect

I would like to detect when a winform starts being dragged and when this stops.

The reason is quite easy: I would like to offer a Ctrl+Z function that sets the window back to its original position, and I need obviusly to store when move starts and ends

Are there any possibilities to do this?

Update 1:
I found how to detect stop dragging:
[C# Form Move Stopped Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-form-move-stopped-event)

I would like to detect START dragging now

Comment: In all versions of Windows, hitting the [Esc]ape key during a Windows drag cancels the operation.

Comment: I would like to Ctrl+Z AFTER someone "dropped" the window

Comment: Are you asking to detect *your* winforms' drag - or any in the whole system?

Comment: Mine, but I found a solution on this website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-form-move-stopped-event now I need to detect BEGIN of form move, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in your [linked article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-form-move-stopped-event):

Form.ResizeBegin and Form.ResizeEnd events handle what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't notice that thing