# How to get the current location of a Windows Form on the screen after drag WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, location

I am coding a WinForms application in Visual Studio C# 2019 and I want to find out the location of the WinForm window (the starting location of the WinForm window after drag WinForm from the desktop).

How can I do that?

Comment: Please be careful not to  misuse tags. Most tags have descriptions that you can read by hovering over them, and the descriptions usually outline cases where you should or shouldn't use the tags. For example, the `[visual-studio]` question should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application, as opposed to code authored within the VS environment. I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885407/winform-dialog-detect-begin-and-end-of-move

Comment: [Control.LocationChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged?view=net-5.0) & [Form.DesktopLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation?view=net-5.0)