# How to reset application settings after restarting Windows OS?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

**Background**

I have a C# windows Form application that sets its default top and left value based on the top and left value of the previous instance of the app opened.

For example, app A opens at left=50 and top=15. User drags the application window to the right so that the app's left=500 and top=50. User exits the application and reopens the application. Its current position is at the position it was last closed (left=500 and top=50).

**Problem**

I want to reset the value to left=50 and top=15 after I have restarted the Windows OS. 
Googling only came out with resetting the values after application quits but what I want is resetting the values after Windows OS restart.

The only way I can think of currently is creating a task in task scheduler that runs a batch script file to adjust the values in `.config` file of the app after windows restart but doing it this way would require one to maintain an extra script file and create a task (more work).

Comment: If you create a volatile key (via `REG_OPTION_VOLATILE`) in the current user registry, it will disappear when the user logs out.  I believe that will include system restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative way is to detect that Windows was restarted since the last application launch and to reset settings accordingly.

The simplistic solution is to store an additional setting, say `LastLaunchTime`, and set it to the current time on application start.

Then you can compare it with a startup time and figure out if the system was restarted since the last launch:

```
DateTime startupTime = DateTime.Now - UpTime;
if(Settings.LastLaunchTime < startupTime) {
    //system was restarted since the last launch, resetting location
}
Settings.LastLaunchTime = DateTime.Now;

//System up time property
TimeSpan UpTime {
    get {
        using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")) {
            uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
        }
    }
}
```

System uptime calculation was taken from here: [Retrieve system uptime using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972105/retrieve-system-uptime-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Do you control the source code?  If yes, start doing this after the startup logic has run once:

On resize event, If the new size is not maximized then store the new size into either the registry or into a config file in Users > (this user) > Appdata > Local > (your company) > (your application)

If a form is just moved and not resized, see this:  [C# Form Move Stopped Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-sharp-form-move-stopped-event)

At app startup, if this value exists and if it is appropriate for the current screen resolution then use it.