# Changing a form location if the main form or any user controls it is on are moved or resized

Tags: winforms, events, handler

[image]

I have created a custom control with an error message form that is located using PointToScreen and I can place in the correct place without an issue, the problem is if the main form is resized moved etc I cannot find a Event handler that will allow me to resize based on a move.

To clarify this I have many Panels and Tab Controls and and it differs from time to time. Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Have you looked at the Form.ResizeEnd Event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?view=netframework-4.8  Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-sharp-form-move-stopped-event

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer from the comment (so that the question has an answer associated with it).

- [Form.ResizeEnd Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?view=netframework-4.8)
- [C# Form Move Stopped Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932800/c-sharp-form-move-stopped-event)